# Unable to git clone project from under proxy

Tags: git, proxy

Recently I've added new SSD to my computer, on this disk I am unable to clone any git repository from under the proxy.

However, if I go to the directory with project on the old SSD (connected to the computer), I am able to pull, fetch etc. No problems with proxy. I am also unable to clone git repo from different directory on the old SSD.

I have set proxy using `git config http.proxy` to the same value as in the old working project. 
Comparing git configs in directory where I can pull and where I cannot clone I've noticed these differences: remote.*, branch.*, gui.* are of course different/missing.

Global git config does not exist in both cases (`git config --global -l` returns no such file or directory).

git clone error:

```
git clone https://user@site.com/dir/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@site.com/dir/project.git': Failed to connect to site.com port 443: Connection refused
```

http configs for both directories:

```
git config --get-regexp http.*
http.sslcainfo C:/Path/To/Cert/cert.crt
http.sslbackend openssl
http.proxy name:pw@server:port
```

I am using Windows 10, without proxy everything works just fine.

Comment: `git config https.proxy name:pw@server:port`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git configuration needed to be set as --global.

I am unsure why setting it without --global didnt work, however this fixed the problem